# Delphi, первые шаги

Tags: delphi, книги

Здравствуйте. Подскажите хорошую литературу для тех, кто начинает изучать Delphi. С чего нужно начинать, какие азы нужны, методы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Культин "Основы программирования в Delphi 7"

Это лучшая книга. Там всё подробно описано, в отличии от Фленова где тупо готовые коды показывают.

Comment: Точно. Фленов, конечно, пишет забавно, но часто хочет не научить, а показать свою образованность.

Answer (score -1):

Фленов "Библия Delphi", "Delphi глазами хакера". В основном, практика, благодаря чему изучение великого и могучего)) будет интересно!

А вообще, исходники, пока, посмотри, покопайся, поменяй что-нибудь,.